# How to bind a command to navigate between pages?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am learning navigation with MVVM as seen here:

[Navigation with MVVM](https://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/12/18/navigation-with-mvvm-2/)

In this tutorial, binding a command for **button** control is implemented by using **ItemsControl** like this:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:HomeViewModel}">
        <local:HomeView />
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:ProductsViewModel}">
        <local:ProductsView />
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>

<DockPanel>
    <Border DockPanel.Dock="Left" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="0,0,1,0">
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding PageViewModels}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Button Content="{Binding Name}"
                            Command="{Binding DataContext.ChangePageCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}"
                            CommandParameter="{Binding }"
                            Margin="2,5"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </Border>

    <ContentControl Content="{Binding CurrentPageViewModel}" />
</DockPanel>
```

If I understand it correctly, it iterates through collection of PageViewModels and binds a button command for every VIewModel. This example works fine and I am able to switch between pages with no problem.

However, I don't want to create buttons iteratively. I want to have two buttons inside a grid with the same command that switches views as in example above. Something like this:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:HomeViewModel}">
        <local:HomeView />
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:ProductsViewModel}">
        <local:ProductsView />
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="5*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Button Grid.Column="0"
        Content="{Binding HomeView.Name}"
        Command="{Binding DataContext.ChangePageCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}"
        CommandParameter="{Binding }"/>

    <Button Grid.Column="1"
        Content="{Binding ProductsView.Name}"
        Command="{Binding DataContext.ChangePageCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}"
        CommandParameter="{Binding }"/>
</Grid>
```

But this doesn't work as I expected. I am able to bind View's names but not the Command. Clicking buttons is doing nothing. DataContext is set to an instance of my ApplicationViewModel. What could be a problem here?

Comment: Have you tried changing the command binding to `{Binding ChangePageCommand...`?

Comment: Yes. The button is now disabled and can't click on it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the `CommandParameter="{Binding }"`, in the first example that binding is pointing to `ItemsSource="{Binding PageViewModels}"`. The second example doesn't have that part, so that binding is failing.

**EDIT>>>>**

To clarify, you must bind the command parameter to an instanciated viewModel in your datacontext.

ViewModel:

```
public IPageViewModel homeViewModel{get; set;}
public IPageViewModel productsViewModel{get; set;}

...

IPageViewModel homeViewModel = new HomeViewModel();
IPageViewModel productsViewModel = new ProductsViewModel();
```

View:

```
CommandParameter="{Binding DataContext.homeViewModel, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}"
```

I dont have a code editor right now, but hope it helps.

Comment: No. This is not a problem,

Comment: Are you sure? where are the binding pointing then? try debugging the binding with a converter to see the value if you are not sure.